# capture by value class members

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11, closures

Is there a way, when writing a lambda function within a member function, to capture fields of the enclosing class by value? The default catch-all `=` doesn't work because when I reference the variable inside the lambda I get instead a dereferencing from the captured this pointer, as well as explicitly naming the variable in the capture list, because I get two compile error: `capture of non-variable <name>`, and `‘this’ was not captured for this lambda function`

Comment: Short answer: Nope. Longer answer: Make function-local references to the data members, then capture those local references by value, but this manual effort is unavoidable.

Comment: @ildjarn how come such a dumb limitation?

Comment: That seems really inconsistent. I can't think why that would be reasonable.

Comment: @Lorenzo : I don't know the rationale. Maybe someone from the committee will stop by with an authoritative answer – paging [@HowardHinnant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/576911/)...

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, data members cannot be captured by value.  A lambda can capture only two kinds of things:

1. the `this` pointer, and
2. nonstatic local variables (that is, variables with automatic storage duration).

As has been noted by ildjarn in the comments, you can create a local variable with a copy of the value of the data member, and capture that local variable by value.

I would argue that *if* explicit by-value capture of a data member was allowed, it could prove confusing, since the behavior of explicit capture would differ from that of implicit capture.  For example, given an accessible data member of type `int` named `m`, it would be odd that the following would produce different results:

```
[=] () mutable { m = 1; } // we modify this->m
[=m]() mutable { m = 1; } // we modify the copy of m that was captured
```

Comment: Wait really?  With `[=] () { m = 1; }` the `this` is captured by value?  I would have expected the `m` to be captured by value.  Then this oddity wouldn't have occured.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Yes.  If you use any nonstatic member in a lambda, the `this` pointer is captured by value.

Comment: Well that's just silly.  I can't imagine why they thought that was a good idea.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  Consistency.  Let's say we call a nonstatic member function from the body of the first lambda:  `f();`.  Do you expect that member function to be called on `*this` or on a copy of `*this`?

Comment: Given a member function, I would expect the lambda to implicitly capture the `this` pointer by value for member functions, but member variables should be captured according to whatever is in the `[]`.  It might appear inconsistent, but that's definitely how I would expect it to behave.

Comment: @MooingDuck:  That doesn't just _appear_ inconsistent.  It _is_ inconsistent, by the definition of "inconsistent."  :-)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Actually your lambda doesn't work: `[=m]() mutable { m = 1; }` still doesn't allow you to capture a member! The only way to capture a member is to name it: `auto mc = m; [mc]() mutable { mc= 1; }`

Comment: @DietmarKühl: [it compiles](http://ideone.com/8DbDg), but you're right that it doesn't quite work as I expected.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The lambda capture always captures variables from the local scope. Member variables are not in the locale scope so you can't touch them. Also, the member is really accessed as `this->m` except that you don't have to write `this->`. That said, we discussed member captures for lambda on Monday and there is no good solution, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @DietmarKühl:  Right.  I was saying that **if** it was allowed, we'd end up with the inconsistency noted in the example.  Apparently the implied "if" was not clear; my apologies to all who may have been confused.  [Aside:  I hope you all are having fun in Portland :-)]

Comment: @MooingDuck: If the code compiles, it is wrong! First off, to capture a variable by value you just name the variable. ... and members can't be captured - yet! ;)

Comment: The C++14 arbitrary expression capture capability should solve this problem, by allowing capture by value and giving it a different name at the same time, thus avoiding the inconsistency.

Comment: It appears that it is possible to capture "this" by value in C++17 : https://github.com/AnthonyCalandra/modern-cpp-features#lambda-capture-this-by-value

Comment: warning: implicit capture of ‘this’ via ‘[=]’ is deprecated in C++20

Answer (score 18):

Yes, simply write the `[<new name>=<your class field>]` construct.
For instance:

```
class MyClass {
    int a;
    void foo() {
        auto my_lambda = [a_by_val=a] {
            // do something with a_by_val
        }

        my_lambda();
    }
}
```

Comment: Capture intializers are a C+14 feature, question is tagged as C++11.

Answer (score -7):

C++ is a language of speed, and one of most important things in design of the language is performance. If standard designers want to implement an idiom a way to capture all variables of a class by value, think of a really huge class and say me do you want to capture them all by value? even to capture all variables that declared in a function(including `this`) there is 2 way:

- by value: variables that defined in a function, leave in stack so they can't be multi megabytes but classes that use heap like `vector` can still be huge. So take care for using this!
- by reference: that actually save stack pointer.

So you see there is no efficient way to capture all variables of a class with value, but you can make a local copy of that class in your function and then capture it by reference!

Comment: not really. I don't want to capture all of them. I just want to capture one, by value, with whatever syntax in the capture list.

Comment: While fast code can be written in C++, I think it is not quite accurate to classify the language being about speed. It is about much more than just speed.

Comment: your argument is moot, lets say I have `BigObject foo;` then it is perfectly fine to capture the whole object by value, but inside a method of `BigObject` you cannot capture a single member, no matter how cheap it might be to copy that single member